# Acceder a un control del formulario principal

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación windowsform con 2 ventanas form y form2, la que se genera por defecto (la considero como la principal) y un 2do form, y quería acceder a un textbox del form principal desde él form2 form para actualizarlo con un botón desde este.

Encontré esta solución que cumplió con lo requerido:

**Formulario creado por defecto:**

```
private void btnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lavhs instancia = new lavhs();
        usuario = txtboxUsuario.Text;
        contra = txtboxContra.Text;

        instancia.Show(this);      // que envia? una instancia del form actual?
    }
```

**Formulario 2:**

```
private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.usuario = txtActualizar.Text; //envio el string a un string statico perteneciente al form principal

        Form form1 = this.Owner; //Obtenemos el dueño del Form (no entiendo)

        TextBox cajaTextoForm1 =  (TextBox)form1.Controls["txtboxUsuario"]; //Obtenemos la caja de texto en Form1 (no entiendo)

        //Le pasamos el texto introducido
        cajaTextoForm1.Text = txtActualizar.Text;
    }
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como se logra obtener acceso al form principal creado por defecto, ya que tengo entendido al crear una instancia de la clase, se genera un form diferente y este no es el caso si se desea modificar un controlador de un form existente que ya esta en ejecución, o estoy errado en como entiendo las cosas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los controles en *C#* se pasan y se asignan por referencia, de modo que mientras no creemos un nuevo control en la asignación (con *new* ..), siempre que asignemos un control a una variable (de su tipo), la variable hara **referencia** a dicho control, al mismo objeto. Yo sugiero :

- Declarar dentro de Form2, un *textBox_par* al que asignaremos *txtbox_usuario*, de modo que cualquier cambio que hagamos a *textBox_par* se aplique directamente a *txtbox_usuario*.

*Nota : Suprimí partes del código que pusiste, entonces, adecua este ejemplo a tu desarrollo.*

Form1.cs ..

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        internal static string usuario;

        private void ingresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            usuario = txtbox_usuario.Text;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
            Form2.textBox_par = txtbox_usuario;
            Form2.Activate();
            Form2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs ..

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        internal TextBox textBox_par;

        private void actualizar_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.usuario = txtActualizar.Text;
            textBox_par.Text = txtActualizar.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No accedes desde un forma directo a los controles del otro, sino que lo haces de forma desacoplada usando interfaces.

Aqui

[Comunicar formulario](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

Explico como podrias lograrlo

La idea es que definas una interfaz como ser

```
interface IForm{
   void Metodo1();
}
```

Entonces haces que el form implemente la interface

```
public class FormPrincipal : Form, IForm{
    //codigo del form
}
```

Cuando invocas el form pasa la instancia en el constructor

```
private void btnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lavhs instancia = new lavhs(this);
    instancia.Show();      
}
```

El acceso a los datos, o realizar acciones del forma principal lo realizas mediante los metodos o propiedades que definas en la interface, pero de uno a otro pasas datos simple no controles.

En el form2 usarias

```
 public class lavhs:Form{

     private IForm _form;

     public lavhs(IForm form){ //este es el constructor
          _form = form;
     }

     //para acceder al form principal lo haces por medio de _form
 }
```

Todo esto lo explico mejor en el artículo que propuse al principio.

Comment: Interfaz es un contrato que se define en el padre y quien desee usar ese "puente" necesita usar la interfaz, es como una puerta trasera que siempre esta abierta a quien la solicite? perdon lei bastante sobre interfaz pero cuesta entender sus principales usos.

Comment: exacto una interace es un contrato que define que funcionalidad va a exponerse, aunque no se si el concepto de "puerta trasera" seria el correcto. Pero imagino entiendes la idea que queria plantear en el ejemplo, con interfaces puede desacoplar la comunicacion entre los forms