# C# Hacer referencia a un control u objeto definido en otra form

Tags: c#

En un proyecto C#  tengo definidas dos forms. Desde una de ellas quiero hacer refencia a un objeto definido en la otra form,  cómo lo hago?   En VB 6.0, se colocaba el nombre de la otra form  seguido de un punto y a continuación el nombre del objeto, en C# no lo he logrado hacer. Gracias de antemano a quien me responda

Comment: Hola @Abimarper, Cuando decís objeto te referís a que tenes una clase implementada donde tienes la implementación del formulario? podés mostrar esa parte del código?

Comment: Hola Alan, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: namespace prueba_multiple_pagina
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

-----------------------------
namespace prueba_multiple_pagina
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
----------------
Desde la accion de un boton en form1 quiero modificar el text de un label en form2.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega este código, para editarla debes hacer click en el link debajo de la misma. si no lo ves te lo dejo aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/24329/edit

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que por objeto te refieres a un control del formulario.

La verdad es que no recomiendo en .net aplicar esta tecnica porque genera acoplamiento entre los forms

El acceso al control del form se realiza local donde lo defines, desde el otro forma realiza acciones invocando metodos que este exponga por medio de una interface.

Aplicarias la tecnica que comento aqui en este artículo

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

Tambien se planteo el mismo tema en esta otra pregunta del foro que podria ayudarte

[Acceder a un control del formulario principal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5215/acceder-a-un-control-del-formulario-principal)

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi aporte, permite recorrer todos los controles, ya sean contenidos o en la forma principal, esto depende de lo que se necesite.

```
public class UtilesControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Permite hacer referencia a un control determinado por medio de su nombre
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nombreControl"> Nombre del Control (es un string)</param>
    /// <param name="pForm"> Forma que contiene el control</param>
    /// <param name="pContenedor">Contenedor donde reside el control a buscar</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Control GetReferCtrl(string nombreControl, Form pForm, Control pContenedor = null)
    {
        // Recorremos la colección de controles del formulario
        //
        if (pContenedor != null)
        {
            foreach (ContainerControl ctrContainer in pForm.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrContainer.Name.ToLower() == pContenedor.Name.ToLower())
                {
                    foreach (Control lblCtrl in ctrContainer.Controls)
                    {
                        if (lblCtrl.Name.ToLower() == nombreControl.ToLower())
                            return lblCtrl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (Control ctrl in pForm.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.Name.ToLower() == nombreControl.ToLower())
                // Devolvemos la referencia y abandonamos la función
                return ctrl;
        }

        return null/* TODO Change to default(_) if this is not a reference type */;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica esto de tu objeto que quieres tener acceso, tenia el mismo problema pero con esto lo solucione

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]